# How to add licenseType

Tags: powershell

I need to get some basic information returned in a Powershell query and I am struggling getting the licenseType included.

Ideally, I want:

```
Name  VMSize  OSType  LicenseType
```

The following code works and shows me the value is correct.

```
Get-AzVM -ResourceGroupName * | `
    Where-Object {$_.StorageProfile.OsDisk.OsType -eq "Windows" -and $_.Name -clike "*" -and $_.LicenseType -ne "Windows_Server"} | `
    Select-Object ResourceGroupName,Name,LicenseType
```

I can't figure out how to add LicenseType (above) to the command below..

```
Get-AzureRmVm -ResourceGroupName "*CRD*" | Select -Property Name, @{Label="VmSize";Expression={$_.HardwareProfile.VmSize}}, @{Label="OsType";Expression={$_.StorageProfile.OsDisk.OsType}}
```

I just want a fourth column that displays the LicenseType value.

Comment: Why not just add `,LicenseType` at the end of the `Select` command?

Comment: For better overview of the code you can insert line breaks where ever PowerShell expects a continuation (***without*** backticks), after a `|`,`,`,`-and` or before a closing `)`,`}`